# Props undefined in jest test

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am using the following test which gives me the error -  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined**:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe("Homescreen Component", () => {
    it("should render without throwing an error", () => {
        const store = mockStore({
            credentials: {
                year: 1,
                group: 1,
                student: 2,
                showStudent: true
            }
        });
        const navigation = { navigate: jest.fn() };

        const tree = renderer
            .create(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <HomeScreen navigation={navigation} />
                </Provider>
            )
            .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

My component `render`:

```
   render() {
        const {
            isLoading,
            categories,
            hasErrored,
            authenticated,
            isLoadingCredentials,
            credentials: { year, group, student, showStudent }
        } = this.props;
```

I am passing `props` in to my component, how come they are `undefined`?

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicator,
    ImageBackground,
    AsyncStorage,
    Platform,
    Dimensions,
    TextInput,
    Alert
} from "react-native";

import {
    setYear,
    setStudent,
    setGroup,
    setCredentials,
    resetForm,
    setAuthenticated
} from "../actions/events";
import { fetchEvents } from "../actions/events";

import { isLoading, isLoadingCredentials, hasErrored } from "../actions/loader";

import ResponsiveImage from "react-native-responsive-image";
import Picker from "./common/Picker";
import SpinnerWithBackground from "./common/SpinnerWithBackground";
import Login from "./Login";
import { data } from "../config/calendars.js";
class HomeScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "",
        headerMode: "screen",
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { landscape: false };
        this.onLayout = this.onLayout.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.showAlert = this.showAlert.bind(this);
        this.onAuthenticate = this.onAuthenticate.bind(this);
        this.onParentChange = this.onParentChange.bind(this);
        this.onGroupChange = this.onGroupChange.bind(this);
        this.onStudentChange = this.onStudentChange.bind(this);
        this.reDirect = this.reDirect.bind(this);
    }

    reDirect() {
        const {
            navigation: { navigate },
            fetchEvents,
            credentials: { student }
        } = this.props;

        if (student) {
            fetchEvents(student);
            navigate("Month");
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {
            navigation: { navigate },

            setCredentials
        } = this.props;
        //www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/fourthyear-spc@rguc.co.uk/events?nextPageToken=2500&key=AIzaSyB77rzW-VzrZAaWJzgiG1Gf-MGEcwn-a-E
        AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").then(authenticated => {
            if (authenticated) {
                this.props.setAuthenticated(true);
            }
        });

        isLoadingCredentials(true);
        AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
            .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    setCredentials(JSON.parse(user));
                    this.reDirect();
                } else {
                    isLoadingCredentials(false);
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                isLoadingCredentials(false);
            });

        isLoadingCredentials(false);
    }

    onParentChange(e) {
        this.props.resetForm();
        this.props.setYear(e);
    }

    onGroupChange(e) {
        if (e !== "") {
            const {
                credentials: { year }
            } = this.props;

            let label = data.years
                .find(option => {
                    return option.id == year;
                })
                .options.find(option => {
                    return option.id == e;
                }).label;

            this.props.setGroup(e, data.years, year, label);
        }
    }

    onStudentChange(e) {
        const {
            credentials: { year, group, showStudent }
        } = this.props;
        if (e !== "") {
            let studentName = data.years
                .find(option => {
                    return option.id == year;
                })
                .options.find(option => {
                    return option.id == group;
                })
                .options.find(option => {
                    return option.id == e;
                }).label;
            this.props.setStudent(e, studentName);
        }
    }

    showAlert() {
        Alert.alert("Incorrect password");
    }

    onAuthenticate(e) {
        if (e == "Undergraduate1") {
            AsyncStorage.setItem(
                "auth",
                JSON.stringify({ authentication: true })
            );
            this.props.setAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
            this.showAlert();
        }
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        const {
            navigation: { navigate },
            credentials: { year, group, student },
            fetchEvents
        } = this.props;

        AsyncStorage.setItem(
            "loggedIn",
            JSON.stringify(this.props.credentials)
        );

        fetchEvents(student || group);
        navigate("Month");
    }

    onLayout(e) {
        const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

        if (width > height) {
            this.setState({ landscape: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ landscape: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            isLoading,
            categories,
            hasErrored,
            authenticated,
            isLoadingCredentials,
            credentials: { year, group, student, showStudent }
        } = this.props;

        if (!authenticated) {
            return <Login onPress={this.onAuthenticate} />;
        }

        return (
            <ImageBackground
                source={require("../img/bkgPhoto.jpg")}
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    width: null,
                    height: null
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={styles.container}
                    onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}
                >
                    {!this.state.landscape ? (
                        <View
                            style={{
                                height: "30%",
                                flexDirection: "row",
                                justifyContent: "space-between"
                            }}
                        >
                            <ResponsiveImage
                                source={require("../img/RGUC_Connect_logo.png")}
                                initWidth="75"
                                initHeight="90"
                            />

                            <ResponsiveImage
                                source={require("../img/logo.png")}
                                initWidth="140"
                                initHeight="70"
                            />
                        </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <ResponsiveImage
                        source={require("../img/CalendarApp_logo.png")}
                        initWidth="250"
                        initHeight="100"
                        style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
                    />
                    {data ? (
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={year}
                            label="Year"
                            onChange={this.onParentChange}
                            options={data.years}
                            style={styles.picker}
                        />
                    ) : null}

                    {year ? (
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={group}
                            label="Group"
                            style={styles.picker}
                            onChange={this.onGroupChange}
                            options={
                                data.years.find(element => {

                                    return element.id == year;
                                }).options
                            }
                        />
                    ) : null}

                    {group && showStudent ? (
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={student}
                            label="Student"
                            style={styles.picker}
                            onChange={this.onStudentChange}
                            options={
                                data.years
                                    .find(element => {
                                        return element.id == year;
                                    })
                                    .options.find(element => {
                                        return element.id == group;
                                    }).options
                            }
                        />
                    ) : null}

                    {(year && group && !showStudent) || student ? (
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={
                                this.state.landscape
                                    ? {
                                          alignItems: "center",
                                          backgroundColor: "#006666",
                                          padding: 10,
                                          width:
                                              Platform.OS === "ios"
                                                  ? "100%"
                                                  : "90%",
                                          alignSelf: "center"
                                      }
                                    : {
                                          alignItems: "center",
                                          backgroundColor: "#006666",
                                          padding: 10,
                                          width:
                                              Platform.OS === "ios"
                                                  ? "100%"
                                                  : "90%",
                                          alignSelf: "center"
                                      }
                            }
                            onPress={this.onSubmit}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Submit</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    ) : null}
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        categories: state.fetchCategories,
        isLoading: state.isLoading,
        hasErrored: state.hasErrored,
        credentials: state.setCredentials,
        isLoadingCredentials: state.isLoadingCredentials,
        authenticated: state.authenticated
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchEvents: id => dispatch(fetchEvents(id)),

    isLoadingCredentials: loadingCredentials =>
        dispatch(isLoadingCredentials(loadingCredentials)),
    setCredentials: credentials => dispatch(setCredentials(credentials)),
    setYear: year => dispatch(setYear(year)),
    setGroup: (group, categories, year, label) =>
        dispatch(setGroup(group, categories, year, label)),
    setStudent: (id, label) => dispatch(setStudent(id, label)),
    resetForm: () => dispatch(resetForm()),
    setAuthenticated: value => dispatch(setAuthenticated(value))
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20,
        flex: 1
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#800080",
        padding: 10
    },
    picker: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        height: 30,
        width: "90%",
        backgroundColor: "white"
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: "white",
        width: "90%",
        alignSelf: "center",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center"
    }
});
```

Comment: Does they come from the redux store in your original file?

Comment: Yes they are all from redux

Comment: Could you also add the snippet on how you get the data from redux to the question please

Comment: when I use `mockStore` with my props, I lose the navigation prop, how can I use `navigation`?

Comment: Did u find an answer for this?